# How to write React Tutorial in ES6 (ES2015)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was rewriting the [React Tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html) in ES6, and got stuck in tutorial16.js. Whats the proper way to write this es5 in es6 format?

```
// tutorial16.js
var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {author: '', text: ''};
  },
  handleAuthorChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({author: e.target.value});
  },
  handleTextChange: function(e) {
    this.setState({text: e.target.value});
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm">
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Your name"
          value={this.state.author}
          onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Say something..."
          value={this.state.text}
          onChange={this.handleTextChange}
        />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
    );
  }
});
```

Here is my CommentForm.jsx that I've written in ES6. If I try to type anything in the form, I get this message in the console: *Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined*
What I'm doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';

class CommentForm extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = { author: '', text: '' }
    }

    handleAuthorChange(e){
        this.setState({author: e.target.value});
    };

    handleTextChange(e){
        this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <form className="commentForm">
                <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" value={this.state.author} onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}/>
                <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." value={this.state.text} onChange={this.handleTextChange}/>
                <input type="submit" value="Post" />
            </form>
        );
    }
}

export default CommentForm;
```

Comment: Since ES6 is backward-compatible, that is _also_ ES5. What specifically do you want changed about it? ES6 classes?

Comment: @loganfsmyth yep. Check my repo: https://github.com/KadoBOT/react-es2015-webpack

Comment: @FelixKling I'll test this later. But looks like that is it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing binding `onChange` handlers to the instance. They are being fired in totally different context, where `this` doesn't point to your `CommentForm`.

It should be instead:

```
<input onChange={this.handleAuthorChange.bind(this)} type="text" placeholder="Your name" value={this.state.author} />
<input onChange={this.handleTextChange.bind(this)} type="text" placeholder="Say something..." value={this.state.text} />
```

Comment: There is a onChange on the inputs. Just roll the scroll bar to the right haha

Comment: You are missing `.bind(this)` part in your code.

Comment: You are right! Thanks!

Comment: @KadoBOT You can alternatively also use the pattern `this.handleAuthorChange = this.handleAuthorChange.bind(this)` in the constructor for every event handler. That way, you don’t need to bind the function every time you need it.

Answer (score 0):

With property initializers (ES6+) it may look like this:

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component {

    state = {
        author: '', text: ''
    };

    handleAuthorChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({author: e.target.value});
    };

    handleTextChange = (e) => {
        this.setState({text: e.target.value});
    };

    render() {
        return <form className="commentForm">
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Your name"
                value={this.state.author}
                onChange={this.handleAuthorChange}
            />
            <input
                type="text"
                placeholder="Say something..."
                value={this.state.text}
                onChange={this.handleTextChange}
            />
            <input type="submit" value="Post" />
        </form>
    }
}
```

Comment: There's no reason for that render function to be an arrow. The more stuff you use as class properties, the slower your code is going to be.

Comment: The reason is just not to bind `this` to render in constructor

Comment: This code didnt worked for me: 
ERROR in ./app/src/component/comment-form.jsx
Module build failed: SyntaxError: /home/ricardo/Documents/Projects/react-es2015-webpack/app/src/component/comment-form.jsx: Unexpected token (5:10)
  3 | class CommentForm extends React.Component {
  4 | 
> 5 |     state = {
    |           ^
  6 |         author: '', text: ''
  7 |     };
  8 |

Here is the link to my repo, with what i have done so far: https://github.com/KadoBOT/react-es2015-webpack

Comment: why would you call the render function in the constructor? you should never call the render function on your own. that arrow does not make sense to me either...and you do have access to "this" anyway, even without the arrow...

Comment: @xCrZx `this` in render will already be correct because React calls it as an instance method. You don't need it to be bound.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Yeah, you are absolutely right, thank you for clearing this moment.